# How to use Nuke preheater for image caching in tableview cell : iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

My `UITabelView` loading slow and scroll is also slow. I fetch images from `Url` with nuke in `UITableViewCell`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = carTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CarDetailsTableViewCell") as! CarDetailsTableViewCell
    if let model = Obj![indexPath.row].model{
         cell.nameLabel.text = model
    }

    if let url = Obj![indexPath.row].image{
         let imageURL = URL(string: url)
         Nuke.loadImage(with: imageURL!, into: cell.carImage)

    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to image loading with Nuke you can follow the below code snippet,

```
    import Nuke

    Nuke.loadImage(with: URL(string: "http://yourImageUrl.jpeg"), into: cell.profileImage)
```

Comment: I have fetched image into a cell but the problem is the loading of table view is very slow and scrolling also slow

Comment: Please post some code with your question, it will help others to find out  the solution

Comment: I have updated the question but its working fine problem is it slows the speed of loading and tableview scrolling I have gone throne nuke documentation they told to use **preheater** for image caching but I am unable to figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the slow loading/scrolling, use a placeholder image. Example code below shows how to preheat the images.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
  var preheater = ImagePreheater(pipeline: ImagePipeline.shared)
  var requests: [ImageRequest]?
  // You need to populate remoteImages with the URLs you want prefetched
  var remoteImages = [URL]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchImages()
  }

  func fetchImages() {
    requests = remoteImages.map {
      var request = ImageRequest(url: $0)
      request.priority = .high
      return request
    }
    if let requests = requests, requests.count > 0 {
      preheater.startPreheating(with: requests)
    }
  }

  deinit {
    if let requests = requests, requests.count > 0 {
      preheater.stopPreheating(with: requests)
    }
  }

  // This is your code modified to use placeholder

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = carTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CarDetailsTableViewCell") as! CarDetailsTableViewCell
    if let model = Obj![indexPath.row].model{
     cell.nameLabel.text = model
    }

    if let url = Obj![indexPath.row].image{
      let imageURL = URL(string: url)
      Nuke.loadImage(with: imageURL!, options: ImageLoadingOptions(
        placeholder: UIImage(named: "your-placeholder-image"),
        transition: .fadeIn(duration: 0.20)
      ), into: cell.carImage)
    }

    return cell
  }

}
```